# Primefaces taglib error on JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces, taglib

I tried to implement PrimeFaces to my project. I download primefaces-3.0.M2.jar and added to build path then I added this taglib to my code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" prefix="p"%>
```

I got this error:

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
```

Is there anyone to help me out?

Answer (score 5):

PrimeFaces 2.2+ does not support JSP view.

Answer (score 2):

Does Primefaces support JSP-style syntax anymore?

You should use Facelets and the standard syntax for declaring taglibs:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
...
```

Remember, JSF is not JSP!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there? Add the necessary libraries to your project and add the following to your the html tag in your view

`xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`

you can now use the p prefix to reference primefaces! :) hope it'll help!

Comment: This answer is not sufficient. The OP should also replace JSP by Facelets, as indicated by the other already given answers. Using Facelets syntax in JSP doesn't magically change JSP to Facelets. As long as you don't have a better answer, there's no need to repeat the already given answers. Stack Overflow is not an old fashioned forum or something where everyone repeats each other :) Once you've earned sufficient reputation, you'll be able to upvote an answer you agree or find helpful.